# Merge two watching batch files

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sass, gulp, watch

I have two `.bat` files with the following code:

#### first.bat

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\ui\assets\styles
sass --watch sass:css
```

#### second.bat

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\ui
gulp watch
```

I am planning to merge the above two files into one. But when I do so, the execution is stopping at the line `sass --watch sass:css`, may be because it is a watching command.

Please suggest if there is any better way to handle it.

Comment: Try `Start sass --watch sass:css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\ui\assets\styles
START sass --watch sass:css
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\ui
START gulp watch
```

Your code runs a file and waits for it to terminate before running the second file. Using the `START` command you make your bat file start the target file without waiting for it to finish.